# Add JSON_OBJECT to one of multiple arrays

Tags: mysql, json

I have several tables whose records have a type identifier. For example a table AUTOS has a MANUFACTURER field. I'd like to be able to create an json_object for each row and add that object to a manufacturer specific array, e.g.

```
{
fordCars: [],
chevyCars: []
}
```

The arrays are members of a parent object (let's name it @parent)

As I indicated I have several such tables that should be treated the same way.

I thought I might define a variable

```
DECLARE @mfgs json;
```

initialize it as follows:

```
SET @mfgs = '{
    "fordCars": [],
    "chevyCars": []
}';
```

I thought I could populate the arrays as follows but the arrays in @mfg are empty:

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN MANUFACTURER='FORD' THEN SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@mfgs, '$.fordCars', JSON_OBJECT(
                'MANUFACTURER',d.MANUFACTURER,
                'MAKE',d.MAKE,
                'MODEL',d.MODEL
            ))
WHEN MANUFACTURER='CHEVY' THEN SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@mfgs, '$.chevyCars', JSON_OBJECT(
                'MANUFACTURER',d.MANUFACTURER,
                'MAKE',d.MAKE,
                'MODEL',d.MODEL
            ))
        END
        from AUTOS d
```

I would then:

```
JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(@parent, @mfgs)
```

The above does not work and in any case requires that I repeat all json/sql mappings for each case statement.

Does anyone know how I can accumulate json_objects in one of multiple arrays based on the value, in this case of MANUFACTURER?

Installation is mySQL 8.023.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An answer that eliminates the issue of having to repeat each of the AUTOS table fields for each grouping of MANUFACTURER. I am still unable however to use JSON_* functions to provide arguments to JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE.

IF someone knows how to accomplish this it would make for a more elegant solution imho.

```
SET json_auto_detail = (select JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(json_auto_detail,
            (select concat('{', GROUP_CONCAT(jsonString SEPARATOR "," ),'}') from (
                SELECT concat('"', mfgArrayName, '":', mfgArrayObj) as 'jsonString' from (
                    (select
                         if (MANUFACTURER='FORD', 'fordCars',
                             if (MANUFACTURER='Chevy', 'chevyCars')) as 'mfgArrayName',
                         json_arrayagg(JSON_OBJECT(
                             'make', MANUFACTURER,
                             'model', MODEL,
                             'id', ID
                             )) as 'mfgArrayObj'
                     from AUTOS 
                     where MANUFACTURER in ('FORD', 'CHEVY')
                     group by MANUFACTURER
                    )
                ) as autos -- up to 2 rows of auto json objects
            ) as mAutos))
        ); -- autos merged with json_auto_detail
```